# Javascript OpenLayers: Google layer behavior with languages

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-api, openlayers

I'm having problem with City names on the google layer. Depending on browser language it's automatically pick the names of Cities on this language.

I have tried language setting here:
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Lang-js.html#OpenLayers.Lang.setCode

But have no effect. Maybe i'm doing it wrong? How to apply this setting on current map object?

For example if language is english town name will be Riga, but if russian, then Рига.
Is it possible somehow to turn this behavior off or force english only map, because when i set markers on one map, it looks different on another.

Resulting marker overlapping text and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer from documentation:

The Google Maps API uses the browser's preferred language setting when displaying textual information such as the names for controls, copyright notices, driving directions and labels on maps. In most cases, this is preferable; you usually do not wish to override the user's preferred language setting. However, if you wish to change the Maps API to ignore the browser's language setting and force it to display information in a particular language, you can add an optional language parameter to the  tag when including the Maps API javascript code, specifying the language to use.
For example, to display a Maps API application in Japanese, add &language=ja to the

```
<script>
```

tag as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
```

Note: loading the API in the manner shown above will use the Japanese language for all users regardless of user preferences. Be sure you wish this behavior before setting this option.

So in your case you should add language=en parameter when you load google maps api.

Comment: Ahaha thanks, just realized it this morning. Should have searched it in google map docs.